# Docker swarm for usb devices

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to build a distributed python application that connects several hosts with android devices over usb.  These hosts then connect over TCP to a central broker for job disbursement.  I'm currently tackling the problem of supporting multiple python builds for developers (linux/windows) as well as production (runs an older OS which requires it's own build of python).  On the surface, docker seems like a good fit here as it would allow me to support a single python build.

However, docker doesn't seem suited well to working with external hardware.  There is the *--device* option to pass a specific device, but that requires that the device be present before the *docker run* command and it doesn't persist across device reboots.  I can get around that problem with *--privileged* but docker swarm currently does not support that (see issue [24862](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24862)) so I'd have to manually setup the service on each of the hosts, which would not only be a pain, but I'd lose the niceness of swarm's automatic deployment and rollout.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make something like this work with docker, or am I just barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: any updates on this issue?

Comment: I have developed a plugin to support this use case. Perhaps you will find it useful: https://github.com/allfro/device-volume-driver

Answer (score 0):

1. you can try developing on docker source code, and build docker from source code to support your requirement.
2. There is a hack, how to do that. In the end of this issue: 
   https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1244